# Validating filetype and display image preview using jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, file-type

I have two scripts that work fine on their own, one validates that the file selected is a `jpeg` and then outputs a alert, which is given below:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.checkFileType = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        allowedExtensions: [],
        success: function() {},
        error: function() {}
    };
    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {

        $(this).on('change', function() {
            var value = $(this).val(),
                file = value.toLowerCase(),
                extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

            if ($.inArray(extension, options.allowedExtensions) == -1) {
                options.error();
                $(this).focus();
            } else {
                options.success();

            }

        });

    });
};

})(jQuery);

$(function() {
$('#image').checkFileType({
    allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg'],
    success: function() {
        alert('success')
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error');

    }
});

});
```

The other one displays a preview of a selected image inside an `<img>` element

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {  

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {

                $('#productImg').show();

                $('#productImg')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)

            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

I'm calling the above function as follows:

```
<input type="file" name="image" class="browse" id="image" onchange="readURL(this);" />
```

What I want to do is combine the two scripts so that if the image is not a `jpeg` it alerts the error like in the first script and then if the image is a `jpeg` it displays the preview like the second script.

Comment: How are you currently calling `readURL`??

Comment: the readURL is currently being called using onchange in the input element. <input type="file" name="image" class="browse" id="image" onchange="readURL(this);"  />

Comment: code blocks are really  unreadable in comments.. please update the info in question… BTW, can't you just specify the second function as the success callback of first by passing `this` as argument?..?If you actually want to modify the function above like a general component,, then we'll have to modify options and pass the reference to the `<img>` element where we want to display the image, etc… is it that necessary?

Comment: How would I specify the second function as the success callback and pass this into it. Sorry I'm new to jquery

Comment: modify `success: function() {…}` with `success: readURL(this),`, and put the alert in second function. If first one success, it'll call second function which will show alert and preview...

Comment: okay tried it and its half way there. The only thing now is the script is still trying to show the preview when the error callback is passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in comments, you can simply specify the second function as the success callback of first function, and show the alert in second function, or call the second function after the alert (*Since you're hardcoding the preview element in second function, it looks like that's enough for the current requirement.*)

If you really want to generalize it, you can try something like below

```
$.fn.checkFileType = function (options) {
var defaults = {
    allowedExtensions: [],
    preview: "",
    success: function () {},
    error: function () {}
};
options = $.extend(defaults, options);
$previews = $(options.preview);
return this.each(function (i) {

    $(this).on('change', function () {
        var value = $(this).val(),
            file = value.toLowerCase(),
            extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1),
            $preview = $previews.eq(i);

        if ($.inArray(extension, options.allowedExtensions) == -1) {
            options.error();
            $(this).focus();
        } else {
            if (this.files && this.files[0] && $preview) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $preview.show().attr('src', e.target.result);
                    options.success();
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            } else {
                options.error();
            }

        }

    });

  });
};
```

You can use it as follows:

```
$('#image').checkFileType({
  allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg',"gif"],
  preview: ".preview",
  success: function () {
    alert('success')
  },
  error: function () {
    alert('Error');
  }
});
```

The image will be set as the `src` of element at the index of your `<input>` among the set of elements matched by the jQuery selector specified in `preview` option.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3aA3L/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily validate the image type in the function readURL(input) itself.

```
function readURL(input) {

      var image = input.files[0]['name'];
      var image_regex =  /^.*\.(jpeg|JPEG)$/;
      if (!image_regex.test(image)) {
                alert("Only jpeg file are accepted");
                return false;
      }

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {  

       var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {

            $('#productImg').show();

            $('#productImg')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)


        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

When the image is uploaded it will validate the image before it is preview. so the user have to upload correct image., similarly you can validate various images too.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lc59/5/)

Comment: I tried this out but the script returns the alert even if the file is a jpeg

Comment: have implemented the fiddle, with your requirements. Give it a try